# Customizing Firefox to look like Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, firefox, internet-explorer, firefox-extensions

Basically I want to be able to customize my Firefox install to look almost 100% identical to Internet Explorer 7/8. I currently have the [vista-aero theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4988/) installed. I just need to be able to change the Firefox icon to the Internet Explorer icon and also change the window title from 'Mozilla Firefox' to 'Internet Explorer'.

The purpose of this is not draw attention to me using Firefox. I am currently running Firefox Portable 3.6.12

Comment: The obvious purpose is lost on me? Are you just trying to trick somebody into thinking you're/they're using IE or do you really just love the look of IE that much?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I am a huge Chrome and Firefox fan, just that at work we aren't 'suppose' to use anything other that IE. So to draw attention away from myself, I'd like this problem solved.

Comment: Then you should have no problem, since you can even use IE engine on Firefox.

Comment: Yes but that isn't the point. I need the GUI to look like Internet Explorer's.

Comment: It was just a comment, since the answers are already given? geez.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to sound like an ass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the icons throughout Firefox, I used [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). Download and run this tool. Open the firefox.exe. Find the icon pack within the exe and replace them with Internet Explorer's icons by opening the iexplore.exe located in \program files\internet explorer.

To change the theme of Firefox to look like Internet explorer, use the [vista-aero theme.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4988/)

End Result:

[image: IE_theme]

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=629966) is how to change the icon. And [here](http://www.techsnack.net/titlebar-tweaks-change-your-firefox-titlebar) is how to change the title. You can even go so far as to use the [IE rendering engine](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10909/) if you really want to.

Comment: The version of titlebar tweaks you linked me to doesn't support the latest version of Firefox. I found one for it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10495/

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid 100% identical isn't possible. Unless you decide to make modifications to source code and compile it yourself (changing icon and some other stuff).

You can get it pretty similar with IE though, not 100%. Search for Internet Explorer at Firefox addons.

**EDIT**: This is the best I can get you:
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/4988/

I'm sure there's a way to change the title bar text but I seriously doubt you can change the icon without some patch or modification.